# How to implement the five star notation in Latex

Tags: symbols, loops

I am creating my own CV and I want to add a command to produce the following :

[image]

I did succeed in doing that, with the following :

```
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\openbigstar[1][0.7]{%
  \scalerel*{%
    \stackinset{c}{-.125pt}{c}{}{\scalebox{#1}{\color{white}{$\bigstar$}}}{%
      $\bigstar$}%
  }{\bigstar}
}

$\bigstar\bigstar\openbigstar[0.5]\openbigstar[.9]\openbigstar[.9]$
```

But each time I need to type five commands, can we dot it in one command taking an argument between 1 and 5 ? (basically do complex loop)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile; what do you include to get the command `\bigstar`?

Comment: I included a lot of other packages, I think its in amssymb

Comment: I'm unsure if this is what you're going for, but putting ratings on your CV might not have the effect you want as it can be subjective. See this question for reference: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48510/rating-skills-on-your-resume#48514

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Welcome! To first approximation you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcounter{iloop}
\newcommand\openbigstar[1][0.7]{%
  \scalerel*{%
    \stackinset{c}{-.125pt}{c}{}{\scalebox{#1}{\color{white}{$\bigstar$}}}{%
      $\bigstar$}%
  }{\bigstar}
}
\newcommand{\Stars}[1]{\ensuremath{\setcounter{iloop}{0}%
\loop\stepcounter{iloop}\ifnum\value{iloop}<#1
\bigstar\repeat
\openbigstar[0.5]
\setcounter{iloop}{0}%
\loop\stepcounter{iloop}\ifnum\value{iloop}<\the\numexpr6-#1\relax
\openbigstar[.9]\repeat}}
\begin{document}
\Stars{5}

\Stars{4}

\Stars{3}

\Stars{2}

\Stars{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not clear to me whether you also want to award fractional stars.

**ADDENDUM**: If you want to allow for fractional ratings, you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newcounter{iloop}
\newcommand\openbigstar[1][0.7]{%
  \scalerel*{%
    \stackinset{c}{-.125pt}{c}{}{\scalebox{#1}{\color{white}{$\bigstar$}}}{%
      $\bigstar$}%
  }{\bigstar}
}
\newcommand{\Stars}[1]{\ensuremath{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\imax}{ifthenelse(int(#1)==#1,#1-1,#1)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xrest}{0.9*(1-#1+\imax)}%
\setcounter{iloop}{0}%
\loop\stepcounter{iloop}\ifnum\value{iloop}<\the\numexpr\imax+1
\bigstar\repeat
\openbigstar[\xrest]%
\setcounter{iloop}{0}%
\loop\stepcounter{iloop}\ifnum\value{iloop}<\the\numexpr5-\imax\relax
\openbigstar[.9]\repeat}}
\begin{document}
\Stars{5}

\Stars{4.2}

\Stars{3.6}

\Stars{2}

\Stars{1.3}

\Stars{0.3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have problems with missing arms of the last filled star when using round numbers, simply subtract 0.01, i.e. 4.99 instead of 5.

Or a Ti*k*Z version, which is obviously much more customizable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand{\Stars}[2][fill=yellow,draw=orange]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.35em,#1]
\foreach \X in {1,...,5}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\xfill}{min(1,max(1+#2-\X,0))}
\path (\X*1.1em,0) 
node[star,draw,star point height=0.25em,minimum size=1em,inner sep=0pt,
path picture={\fill (path picture bounding box.south west) 
rectangle  ([xshift=\xfill*1em]path picture bounding box.north west);}]{};
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\Stars{4.5}
 
\Stars{4.2}

\Stars{3.6}

\Stars{2}

\Stars{1.3}

\Stars{0.3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer, this is what I was looking for, but it would be more perfect if fractional stars are included.

Comment: @Elaqqad I added them. Please note that if you were to consider using `tikz`, the fractional fill could be adjusted more easily/precisely.

Comment: Perfect, I have already included ```tickz``` in my packages for other reasons, how could you go to adjust that precisely ?

Comment: that's Perfect, I ended up using ``tickz``.

Comment: @Elaqqad Glad to hear! If you look at the code in my user profile, you can see why I am very supportive of this choice. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

TeX is technically Turing-complete, but some programming concepts are a bit more difficult than in other languages.  Loops are one.  But they are certainly doable.  I don't know where you're getting `\bigstar` from, so I can't do that specifically; but here's the general, TeX way to do a loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcount\loopi\loopi=0
\loop\ifnum\loopi<5
    Hey
    \advance\loopi by1
\repeat
\end{document}
```

You use `\loop`, then an `\ifnum` to give your condition.  It will then repeat whatever is between that `\ifnum` and your `\repeat` command.  Make sure that you increment your loop-control variable (here, `\loopi`) within your loop, or you'll get an infinite loop.

The above will print "Hey" five times.  I understand that there are more LaTeXy ways to do this, and that `pgf` may have some very easy loop commands; but I can't speak to them.  This is the basic TeX way, anyway.

Your specific question seems to require manipulating fractional values, which is also a bit tougher in TeX; maybe look into the `fp` package?  You could also perhaps use an integer and just append it to `0.`:

```
\newcount\loopi\loopi=1
\loop\ifnum\loopi<6
    0.\the\loopi,
    \advance\loopi by1%
\repeat
```

That will print `0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5`; maybe you could use this in your `\openbigstar` commands.

Comment: I did not know that it is Turing Complete ! very cool information.

Answer (score 4):

Adjusted TikZ version from accepted answer

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand{\stars}[2][fill=black,draw=black]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.34em,#1]
\foreach \X in {1,...,5}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xfill}{min(1,max(1+#2-\X,0))}
\path (\X*1em,0) 
node[star,draw, ultra thin,star point height=0.23em,minimum size=0.75em,inner sep=0pt,
path picture={\fill (path picture bounding box.south west) 
rectangle  ([xshift=\xfill*0.722em]path picture bounding box.north west);}]{};
}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\stars{4.5}
 
\stars{4.2}

\stars{3.6}

\stars{2}

\stars{1.3}

\stars{0.3}

\end{document}
```

[image: stars]

Answer (score 3):

I used this in `komacv`:

```latex
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{x}
\newcommand{\skill}[1]{%
    \forloop{x}{0}{\value{x} < #1}{%
        $\textcolor{colortheme}\bullet$
    }%
    \forloop{x}{#1}{\value{x} < 5}{%
        $\textcolor{colortheme}\circ$
    }%
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody needs a solution for circles instead of stars use this:

```latex
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}

% open bullet macro
\newcommand{\openbullet}{\ensuremath{\circ}}%
\newcommand{\solidbullet}{\ensuremath{\bullet}}%
\newcounter{counter_skilllevel}% counter variable
\newcommand{\skilllevel}[1]{% define skill-level function
    \setcounter{counter_skilllevel}{0}% reset counter
    \loop% solid bullet loop
        \textcolor{color1}{\Large\solidbullet}\,% draw filled circle and small space
        \stepcounter{counter_skilllevel}% i++
        \ifnum \value{counter_skilllevel}<#1% continue if target level not reached yet
    \repeat% close loop
    \loop% open bullet loop
        \ifnum \value{counter_skilllevel}<5% check max condition first
        \stepcounter{counter_skilllevel}% i++
        \textcolor{darkgray}{\Large\openbullet}\,% draw unfilled circle and small space
    \repeat%
}
```

Comment: That seems to be an answer to another question.